# I install php codesniffer and i got this error

Tags: php

I have Brackets install and i get PHP linter but i get this error plus the end tag ?> is not supported

```
Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
```

What is mean ?

Comment: It's not recommended to put ?> at the end of your file. Just remove it, and add a new blank line

Comment: And this error Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found ?

Comment: but why it needed a new line ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18743/whats-the-point-in-adding-a-new-line-to-the-end-of-a-file

Comment: Thanks, I still got a question i write a new code and i get this error in Mess Detector  Strack  Trace :  and is empty why ?